# How can I use an analyzer in a nested query in Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, search

I am trying to run a query in a nested object with an analyzer but it is not working. Whenever I make a query using said analyzer there are no hits. If I remove I get the correct results but not with the filters.

I basically need that my query in these nested fields use my "lowercase", "asciifolding" and "stopwords_filter" filters.

I am using elasticsearch 7.13.4 (It is not possible to upgrade)

Here is my test and example index (simplified for the sake of the example):

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "accent_filter": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "stopwords_filter"
                    ],
                    "char_filter": [
                        "alphabets_char_filter"
                    ],
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "stopwords_filter": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": "_brazilian_",
                    "ignore_case": "true"
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "alphabets_char_filter": {
                    "pattern": "[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]",
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "replacement": " "
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "service_x_users": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "_id": {
                        "properties": {
                            "value": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "norms": false,
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "norms": false,
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        },
                        "analyzer": "accent_filter"
                    },
                    "email": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "norms": false,
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        },
                        "analyzer": "accent_filter"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my test data (simplified)

```
{
  "service_x_users" : [
    {
      "name" : "Alice",
      "email" :  "abc@abc.com"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Péter",
      "email" :  "cde@cde.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

This query below is not working as expected. It should still return my document but it returns as having no hits.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "service_x_users",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "service_x_users.name.keyword"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "query_string": {
                      "query": "Alice",
                      "fields": ["service_x_users.name.keyword"],
                      "analyzer": "accent_filter"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove the analyzer field, it works correctly. Just on nested fields I am getting this behaviour. On non-nested objects it works as intended.

With analyzer:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Without analyer:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.6931472,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "index_test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.6931472,
                "_source": {
                    "service_x_users": [
                        {
                            "name": "Alice",
                            "email": "abc@abc.com"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Péter",
                            "email": "cde@cde.com"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```